# ng-repeat inside of bootstrap modal does not get updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal dialog to handle chat logic view in my angularjs app.

I have a listener such this

```
$rootScope.$on('msg:received', handleNewMessageAction);
```

and handler for it

```
function handleNewMessageAction(e, data) {
    var selTId = getSelectedThread().id;

    if (data.message.threadId == selTId) {
        data.message.getter = SessionService.getAuthProfile();
        $scope.messages.push(data.message);
        getSelectedThread().lastMessage.message = data.message.message;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.threads.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.threads[i].id == data.message.threadId) {
                $scope.threads[i].lastMessage.message = data.message.message;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.$apply();
}
```

everything works well when I open dialog first time . But if I navigate to another sate (I am using ui-router) and then open modal again. I does not update view when handler pushed new item in array .I have debugged it more then once .Handler works fine it pushes new item in array (messages) but array in view does not get updated;

Here is the function which opens the dialog.

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/directives/modals/messages.html',
        windowClass: 'extended-message-modal',
        scope: $scope
    });

    return false;
};
```

and here is a small part of modal template

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages track by $index">
    <div class="message-other-side pull-left" ng-if="msg.sender.id != authId">
        <div class="pull-left message-profile-image">
            <img ng-src="{{getImage(msg.sender.gender,msg.sender.avatar)}}">
        </div>
        <div class="message-content pull-left">{{msg.message}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="message-my-side pull-right" ng-if="msg.sender.id == authId">
        <div class="message-content pull-left">
            {{msg.message}}
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left message-profile-image">
            <img ng-src="{{getImage(msg.sender.gender,msg.sender.avatar)}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

define a `modal controller` and use this controller scope to get and update the data inside modal.

```
$scope.open = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
    });
  };
```

If you're passing data to your modal from some other controller then you can use `resolve` to make it available in template scope.

```
$scope.open = function (dataFromOtherController) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
        data: function () {
          return dataFromOtherController;
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Now you can access `$scope.data` in modal controller and template.

Comment: you mean I have to specify {controller : someFunction} in my modal params ?

Comment: Check the documentation of angular-ui. It provides functionality to specify separate controller for your modal. UPDATED MY ANSWER

Comment: Does not work ... I don't have problem with accessing data . My problem is
the following. Modal and data accessing works fine on first opening. but if I close modal .. and navigate to some other state in my app and open again .. now pushing new item in array  has  not any affect on view.

Comment: can you make a fiddle and post the link? also try checking with debugger whether your modal is receiving the data or not.

Comment: unfortunately I can't make a fiddle because my project is to large , and there are many libraries and services such as (pubnub angular service) and so on . I think handling chat logic in fiddle is a bad idea. It can take more time . Anyway thank you very much for trying to help.